# Ajax call response as question mark instead of Arabic characters

Tags: ajax, arabic

I am making a ajax call POST request(sending audio as a blob) to the server. I am expecting Arabic characters as response but I am getting question mark instead.

```
$.ajax({
        "async":true,
        "url": url,
        "method":"POST",
        "contentType": false,
        "processData": false,
        "data":data_audio,
        success:function(response){}
```

Response is coming as - {result: "?????.", status: "success"}

Comment: To limit the scope of the problem, you should try to send a HTTP POST request directly (without using JavaScript), to see if the problem is with the request or with the jQuery AJAX encoding.

Comment: we checked it in postman. Response is coming as Arabic characters only but here via ajax call it is coming as question marks